# follow loading progress of huge XML files

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I try to follow the loading progress of big XML files (I'm not the provider of these files) in dotnet (C#, framework 3.5 SP1) : from 1 MB to 300 MB over a network file share.

I use an XmlReader for loading purpose instead of direct XmlDocument.Load method for speed up the loading process.

By the way I found nowhere on internet/document on how to follow this loading progress: no delegates/events seem exist. Is there any way to perform this task ? Having the kind of functionnality for XML saving purpose could be a nice to have.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you loading these files, in a DOM/Database or something else? Are you reading and processing them node by node or loading putting them in memory?

Comment: I assume I forget to put some information :
I load these XML files for an API (I have source, but I prefer not to edit the logic/parsing) that parse the file (mainly with Xpath). This API accept in XML param a path to a XML file (and use XmlReader) or a Stream.

I do not really care about the parsing process which is quick, only focusing on the loading in memory process.

Comment: another latest processing model is called VTD-XML, availabe in C#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are reading from a stream here is a (non-perfect) example of how to do it...
Basically the ProgressStreamWrapper wraps the file stream and raises an event whenever Position is changed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading big file...");

        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\bigfile.xml");
        ProgressStreamWrapper progressStreamWrapper = new ProgressStreamWrapper(fileStream);
        progressStreamWrapper.PositionChanged += (o, ea) => Console.WriteLine((double) progressStreamWrapper.Position / progressStreamWrapper.Length * 100 + "% complete");
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(progressStreamWrapper);

        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            //read the xml document
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


public class ProgressStreamWrapper : Stream, IDisposable
{
    public ProgressStreamWrapper(Stream innerStream)
    {
        InnerStream = innerStream;
    }

    public Stream InnerStream { get; private set; }

    public override void Close()
    {
        InnerStream.Close();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
        InnerStream.Dispose();
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        InnerStream.Flush();
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return InnerStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        int endRead = InnerStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
        OnPositionChanged();
        return endRead;
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return InnerStream.BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
    }

    public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        InnerStream.EndWrite(asyncResult);
        OnPositionChanged(); ;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        long seek = InnerStream.Seek(offset, origin);
        OnPositionChanged();
        return seek;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        InnerStream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int read = InnerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        OnPositionChanged();
        return read;
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        int readByte = InnerStream.ReadByte();
        OnPositionChanged();
        return readByte;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        InnerStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        OnPositionChanged();
    }

    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        InnerStream.WriteByte(value);
        OnPositionChanged();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return InnerStream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return InnerStream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanTimeout
    {
        get { return InnerStream.CanTimeout; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return InnerStream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return InnerStream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return InnerStream.Position; }
        set
        {
            InnerStream.Position = value;
            OnPositionChanged();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler PositionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPositionChanged()
    {
        if (PositionChanged != null)
        {
            PositionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public override int ReadTimeout
    {
        get { return InnerStream.ReadTimeout; }
        set { InnerStream.ReadTimeout = value; }
    }

    public override int WriteTimeout
    {
        get { return InnerStream.WriteTimeout; }
        set { InnerStream.WriteTimeout = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could provide as API param a Stream so I will look to this kind of solution (PositionChanged event). Will update today.

Comment: I think we had the same idea, but your code was here first, so a definite +1 ;-p

Answer (score 2):

With the inbuilt loaders there isn't much; you could, however, write an intercepting stream - load your document from this stream, and expose the `Position` via events? i.e. raise an event in the `Read` method (at intervals)?

---

Here's an example that supports updates during both read and write:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
class ChattyStream : Stream
{
    private Stream baseStream;
    public ChattyStream(Stream baseStream)
    {
        if (baseStream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("baseStream");
        this.baseStream = baseStream;
        updateInterval = 1000;
    }
    public event EventHandler ProgressChanged;
    protected virtual void OnProgressChanged()
    {
        var handler = ProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (baseStream == null) throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
    }
    protected Stream BaseStream
    {
        get { CheckDisposed(); return baseStream; }
    }
    int pos, updateInterval;
    public int UpdateInterval
    {
        get { return updateInterval; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
            updateInterval = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Increment(int value)
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            pos += value;
            if (pos >= updateInterval)
            {
                OnProgressChanged();
                pos = pos % updateInterval;
            }
        }
    }
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int result = BaseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        Increment(result);
        return result;
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        BaseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        Increment(count);
    }
    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        BaseStream.SetLength(value);
    }
    public override void Flush()
    {
        BaseStream.Flush();
    }
    public override long Position
    {
        get { return BaseStream.Position; }
        set { BaseStream.Position = value; }
    }
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return BaseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return BaseStream.Length; }
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return BaseStream.CanWrite; }
    }
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return BaseStream.CanRead; }
    }
    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return BaseStream.CanSeek; }
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && baseStream != null)
        {
            baseStream.Dispose();
        }
        baseStream = null;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public override void Close()
    {
        if (baseStream != null) baseStream.Close();
        base.Close();
    }
    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        int val = BaseStream.ReadByte();
        if (val >= 0) Increment(1);
        return val;
    }
    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        BaseStream.WriteByte(value);
        Increment(1);
    }

}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        /* invent some big data */
        const string path = "bigfile";
        if (File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
        using (var chatty = new ChattyStream(File.Create(path)))
        {
            chatty.ProgressChanged += delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing: " + chatty.Position);
            };
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(chatty))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("xml");
                for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
                {
                    writer.WriteElementString("add", i.ToString());
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }
            chatty.Close();
        }


        /* read it */

        using (var chatty = new ChattyStream(File.OpenRead("bigfile")))
        {
            chatty.ProgressChanged += delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading: " + chatty.Position);
            };

            // now read "chatty" with **any** API; XmlReader, XmlDocument, XDocument, etc
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(chatty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using DataSet.Read()?

or,

```
// Create the document.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(file);

        // Loop through all the nodes, and create the list of Product objects .
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        foreach (XmlElement element in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            Product newProduct = new Product();
            newProduct.ID = Int32.Parse(element.GetAttribute("ID"));
            newProduct.Name = element.GetAttribute("Name");

            // If there were more than one child node, you would probably use
            // another For Each loop here and move through the
            // Element.ChildNodes collection.
            newProduct.Price = Decimal.Parse(element.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);

            products.Add(newProduct);
        }
```

Comment: Basically, I try to focus on the loading mechanism and not the parsing one : the parsing process is done by an external API.

In your example, 'doc.Load(file);' will load the overall XML file at this step and going further only when the file will be loaded in memory.